# How to login to Collibra from AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, data-lineage, collibra

I am trying to use Collibra by installing it using AWS Marketplace AMI that they offer and launched the EC2 instance. However, when I try to login to Collibra using the IP Address of the EC2 instance and I am unable to connect. I tried adding the IP Address in the proxy settings but did notwork. Any idea what should I do?

I tried logging into Collibra website using the Public IPv4 Address and also tried connecting using the IPv4 DNS name as well. Neither of them worked. I have also tried launching it multiple times but with no success